# Android application in Xiaomi block web requests with mobile network

Tags: android, miui, xiaomi

I made an application in Android Studio that make requests to a Web API and it's working fine. I used Retrofit to make the connection to server and make the calls.

When I open the application with Wifi it works correctly but when I turn on the mobile network Xiaomi somehow blocks the requests. **The problem is in the phone and not in the server or application because I tried that procedure in other Android smartphones and works fine with both ways.** So I checked all permissions in the Xiaomi and the app can acess to Wifi and mobile network but in reality the requests are being blocked...

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: any update on this?!

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow mobile network for your application in Xiaomi `Security` app?

Security -> Data usage-> Restrict data usage

then select your app and turn on mobile networks

Comment: @JFCM okay, what retrofit gave you as response? I mean error/exception/error code

Comment: 404 not found, but I think the problem is not in the application because it is working fine on other phones

Comment: @JFCM 404 is a response from server, it means connection is okay. But there can be a few options 1) You have problems with proxy server of your provider 2) Xiaomi somehow changes your url to another

Comment: The server is working correctly because it works fine in other phones. I will check it again in log if Xiaomi changes the url but the problem probably is in a configuration on the phone that I can't find it...

Comment: @JFCM try to check other urls, which are guaranteed work